# Spring Oauth2 + User Registration

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have problem with Spring Oauth2 again. I know this topic is not easy to suggest sth or check the codes because we have too much configuration. 
My project has 3 different servers, Authentication server, resource server and front-end server. I want to put register.html to user's registration in front-end project(under Angularjs files) but when I make request to the related url (http://localhost:7080/app/#register) its redirecting to the login page (http://localhost:9080/auth-service/login) only for a second i can see my register.html content but after that its going to login page.
The question is, where should i put this register.html, it should be under front-end project or authentication server ?

My authentication server and front-end server codes are;

```
    @Configuration
    public class AuthServerSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    auth.authenticationProvider(userAuthProviderService());
}
private CsrfMatcher csrfRequestMatcher = new CsrfMatcher();
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    /*http.csrf().disable();*/
    http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfRequestMatcher);
    http
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            /*.failureUrl("")*/.successHandler(new AuthSuccessHandler()).permitAll()
            .and()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access","/register")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

}

@Bean
public UserAuthProviderService userAuthProviderService(){
    return new UserAuthProviderService();
}

private class CsrfMatcher  implements RequestMatcher {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class UIServiceMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(UIServiceMain.class, args);
}

@Configuration
protected static class SecurityConfiguration  extends OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.logout().and()
                .antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/", "/login","/register.html").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable(); //FOR EMBED MAP
    }

    //unused
    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                        .getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null
                            && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    //unused
    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in your UI server try to create websecurity with /register.hml enabled, something like this

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/register.html")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
}
```

edit:
or maybe in your current configuration remove `.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()` and add `and()               .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()`

so finally it could be something like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.logout().and()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/", "/login","/register.html").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable() //FOR EMBED MAP
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- I can't think of a good reason not to put your *.html anywhere other than front end server.
- Also, in general, you should permit access to your static UI components publically, like @bilak mentioned:

`.antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/", "/login","/register.html").permitAll()`

- If you are able to see `register.html` page at all (assuming unauthenticated user) then it is public already
- Perhaps, there is a webservice call on `register.html`'s load event that is behind Spring security that is triggering the auth flow.